# With(context) using picasso is now get() instead. How do I get(context) or make my code load the pictures from lorempixel if notrom pi

Tags: java, android, get, picasso

How do I use the get() to replace with(context) in Picasso.with(context)

If I just switch out with(context) with get() it doesn't retrieve the resources I need. I'm not quite sure what do as I am learning to program currently so if I could get an explanation as well it would be much appreciated.

```
public class TaskListAdapter extends
RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    static String[] fakeData = new String[] {
            "One",
            "Two",
            "Three",
            "Four",
            "Five",
            "Ah ... ah ... ah!"
    };

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i){
        //create a new view
        CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_task, parent, false);

        //wrap it in a ViewHolder
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    public static String getImageUrlForTask(long taskId){
        return "http://lorempixel.com/600/400/cats/?fakeId=" + taskId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i){
        Context context = viewHolder.titleView.getContext();

        viewHolder.titleView.setText(fakeData[i]);

        //set the thumbnail image
        Picasso.with(context).load(getImageUrlForTask(i)).into(viewHolder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return fakeData.length;
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CardView cardView;
        TextView titleView;
        ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(CardView card){
            super(card);
            cardView = card;
            titleView = card.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            imageView = card.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect my to make my imageview components show varying pictures of cats (http:lorempixel.com/600/400/cats/?fakeId=) but they appear blank.

Comment: What version of picasso library you are using ?

Comment: `Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);`

Comment: try this `Picasso.get().load(getImageUrlForTask(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition())).into(viewHolder.imageView)`

Comment: using picasso:2.71828

Comment: neither of those to lines seem to have worked